# Arithmetic and Scaling Factor

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I found the below question in a Russian Math book.

The number 608 now becomes 608000.

608000 - 608 = 607392 -- Is this correct?
***[By how many ones did the number increase?]***

608000/608 = 1000 -- Is this correct?
***[By what factor did the number increase?]***

**Question:-
Three zeros were added to the right of the number 608. By how many ones did the number increase? By what factor did the number increase?**

Comment: The point is to understand decimal notation, that putting three zeros on the right is the same as multiplying by $1000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computations are correct. $608000-608=607392$ can be verified by the subtraction algorithm from elementary school.  The answer to by how many ones did the number increase is $607392$.  That is the point of subtraction.  What they are looking for is that adding three zeros is the same as multiplying by $1000$.  $608000=608\cdot 1000$, so $608000-608=608(1000-1)=608 \cdot 999=607392$

Comment: The wording was a bit different and I just wanted to be sure before I teach my son. Thanks Very Much